# How balanced is the Thrall of Fraz-Urb'luu PrC

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

Specifically the 10th level feature *Alter Reality*.

> Alter Reality (Sp): At 10th level, a thrall of Fraz-Urb'luu gains the ability to transform an illusion spell into reality, once per day. This duplicates the effects of a wish spell, save that it cannot grant inherent bonuses to ability score or duplicate any spell of 8th level or higher. The reality to be created must first be manifested with an illusion spell of at least 3rd level before this ability can be used.

Even 1/day this seem unimaginably strong because with say *Mirage Arcana* or *Major image* I could create ANYTHING the illusion could simulate, and there is no duration which makes it even more broken.
Am I missing something or misinterpreting it or is this really as strong as I think it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 10th-level thrall of Fraz-Urb’luu is a 17th-level character, but casts spells as a 14th-level spellcaster, at best. Had they just stayed in, say, wizard, they would just be able to prepare and cast *wish*, possibly multiple times per day. Their *alter reality* ability “saves” them a 9th-level spell slot, but it can’t do everything that *wish* can—and getting that ability requires losing *all* of their 9th-level **and 8th-level** spell slots.

Now, alter reality also saves a bunch of XP, since *wish* is pricey and as a spell-like ability, *alter reality* doesn’t have any components. That’s nice. But you have devoted 10 levels—**3 of which cost you spellcasting progression**—to get it. That isn’t generally considered a great trade.

Now, is a thrall of Fraz-Urb’luu overpowered? Probably. But also probably less so than they would be as a simple 17th-level wizard. The game is just broken at levels that high.

Comment: Could you make an illusion of a creature who was fanatically devoted to you  and could grant divine ranks and make it real for easy greater-to-over-deityship?

Comment: @MarineByzaro *Alter reality* has the effect of the *wish* spell. Is what you describe an effect of the *wish* spell? Well, maybe—it could be one of the “greater effects” that *wish* mentions. But *wish* also mentions a fairly dire warning to go along with those. In other words, your DM **could** let you use *alter reality* to get that, but almost-certainly your attempt to achieve that through *alter reality* would result in something else entirely—and probably not something you want. (Also, I would wonder how you would recreate those things via sight, sound, temperature, etc. only.)

Comment: "Also, I would wonder how you would recreate those things via sight, sound, temperature, etc. only" You create the image of a kobold named Pun-Pun, of course. ;)

Comment: @nick012000 Don’t know how you would indicate the kobold’s true identity via illusion, much less his fanatical devotion to anyone.

Comment: A fanatically devoted kobold would look just as a normal kobold would but there is still a difference unless your DM houserules that it isn't part of the illusion if it can't be seen as part of it

Comment: @MarineByzaro No houserule: “The reality to be created must first be manifested with an illusion spell of at least 3rd level before this ability can be used.” You have to have an illusion matching the reality you want to create in order to get it. If you don’t have an ability to create “illusory fanaticism” then you can’t do that.